# python3 running old version of script

Tags: python, linux

I've changed a script by commenting out a section and adding some print statements above it for testing purposes, the problem is when I run the script from any other directory than the one it's in, python is running the old version of the script.
Clearing `__pycache__` had no effect.

Here's the python script in question:

```
import discord
import watson
import configparser
import os
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from getpass import getuser

print("WHY ISN'T THIS BEING CALLED!!")

#print(os.getcwd())
#os.chdir("/home/{}/discordBotStaging".format(getuser()))
#print(os.getcwd())

#if(not os.path.isfile("./config.ini")):
#    print("No config file found, make sure you have one in the same directory as this python script\nexiting")
#    quit()

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("./config.ini")

TOKEN = config["DEFAULT"]["DISCORD_KEY"]
BOT_PREFIX = ("!", "$")

client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@client.command(name="memealyze",
        description="When uploading image include command \"!memealyze\" | \"!Memealyze\" | \"!MemeAlyze\" | \"!ma\" as a comment",
        brief="Neural network put to good use",
        aliases=["Memealyze", "MemeAlyze", "ma"],
        pass_context=True)

async def GetMemeContents(context):
    await client.say("Sending image to the mothership, hold tight.")

    if(not context.message.attachments):
        await client.say(
                "Couldn't find image attachement. Make sure you include \"!memealyze\" or any of it's variants as a comment when submitting an image")
        return

    imageUrl = str(context.message.attachments[0]["url"])
    messageContent = ""
    resultDict = watson.ReturnWatsonResults(imageUrl)

    for key,val in resultDict.items():
        messageContent += "{} : {}%\n".format(key, val)

    await client.say("Done, the boys at IBM said they found this:\n" + messageContent)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

And here's the issue:

```
yugnut@RyzenBuild:~$ python3 discordBotStaging/main.py
No config file found, make sure you have one in the same directory as this python script
exiting
yugnut@RyzenBuild:~$
```

---

```
yugnut@RyzenBuild:~/discordBotStaging$ python3 main.py
WHY ISN'T THIS BEING CALLED!!
^Cyugnut@RyzenBuild:~/discordBotStaging$
```

EDITS:

@ShadowRanger suggestions:

> Try moving the print above all the imports in your script.

This yields promising results, I do get output by trying this but right after that I still run into the same issue

> You can't use relative paths like that if the config file is expected to be in the same directory as the script; you have to do `config.read(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config.ini'))`

I think my ignorance is showing :^), I changed this in my script as well

After making these edits along with trying to run the script after commenting out my `import configparser` line I still get the same error.

Comment: Try moving the `print` above all the imports in your script. I'm suspicious that one of your imports may be trying to load config data from a working directory relative path (e.g. like `config.read("./config.ini")`), and failing before you even reach your `print`. You can't use relative paths like that if the config file is expected to be in the same directory as the script; you have to do `config.read(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config.ini'))`

Comment: Ah, okay I'll give that a shot and report back

Comment: But if you're using Python 3, check out the `pathlib` library as a replacement for many `os.path` things! E.g. `config.read(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / "config.ini")`. I feel like `pathlib` deserves more love than it gets

Comment: I'll be sure to checkout `pathlib` as well, I hadn't even heard of that until now, sounds sweet.